# What does "cd `echo $0 | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/'` " do in bash script?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to understand [a script written in a quantum-espresso example](https://github.com/maxhutch/quantum-espresso/blob/master/PW/examples/example01/run_example). In it I found this expression:

```
# run from directory where this script is
cd `echo $0 | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/'` # extract pathname
```

But, I can't understand  what `s/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/` means.

Comment: As I know  `s/(.)/./\1/` is a little regular expression for getting path from string line

Comment: yes I know, but why we use it? can I eliminate this line? I can't find its usage.

Comment: If you know that it's a regular expression intended to extract a path from a string, what are you not understanding here?

Comment: It looks like a long-winded, slow and broken way of writing `cd "${0%/*}"`.  But that looks like a dangerously fragile thing to do unless you're able to guarantee that the script will always be executed with a (relative or absolute) filename, rather than being found on `$PATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $0 | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/'
```

gets the folder that the script is running in.

For example if you are running a script called `/home/mike/test.sh`, it gives you `/home/mike/`

and the whole command changes into that directory.

try this

```
echo this is where we started
pwd
cd `echo $0 | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/'` # extract pathname
echo now we are here
pwd
```

And then run the script from a different directory than the one where the script is located.

---- answer the question ---

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/'
```

removes the last piece of the path

try this

```
echo this/is/a/test | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/'
echo this/is/a/test/ | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/'
echo this/is/a/test.sh | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/'
```

and since `echo $0` should give you a file (the current script), the whole expression should give you the folder where that script is saved.

as for how it works, see this answer to the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50148667/5203563

Comment: That's what it's intended to do, but worth adding is that in some cases it'll be wrong, not necessarily through any fault of the user running it.

Comment: Few hopefully helpful hints. This construct would really mostly help obfuscate the code. When dealing with `/`, using other delimiters in regexp would be nice. Instead of replacing whole line with back reference, one could just chop of the last part without `/` like: `sed 's#[^/]*$##'`. But really, I'd expect `dirname $0` do be used for this very purpose.

Comment: @Alex The simplest is when `$0` is not an absolute path, e.g. when the command is found from `$PATH`.

Comment: Another failure case is when any part of the path contains whitespace characters.

Answer (score 3):

It is a path extractor as the comment section says.

A little explanation into the regular expression:

```
s/                # sed mode

\(.*\)\/.*/       # A greedy capture group followed by a slash 
                  # '(.*)/.*', it will try to match as many characters
                  # as possible (include slashes) before the 
                  # last occurrence of '/'.
                  # A non-greedy modifier '?' will make it look for 
                  # the first occurrence of '/',
                  # as in  '(.*?)/.*'. All special charters are escaped
                  # here, I removed the '\'s for better readability.

\1/               # '\1' is referring back to the 'first capture group 
                  # in the regexp, so the 'sed' command replaces 
                  # the entire match with things between the first 
                  # pair of capturing parentheses.
```

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression used is:

```
(.*)\/.*
```

- In the 1st capturing group `(.*)`, `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators) between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `\/` matches the character `/` literally
- `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators) between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Since you're using the regex via tool `sed`, you need to escape the expression: parentheses `(` and `)` become `\(` and `\)`. The `\1` returns the 1st capturing group. In regard to a file path, it means the directory in which the file is located.

So, this script gets the folder that the script is running in as mentioned by @Alex028502.

I also recommend https://regex101.com/, a website allowing you to evaluate your regex online for free.